# Return the signed value in certain bits range

Tags: c++, binary, bit

The assignment:

- return the signed value of the 4 bits in bits 0-3
- return the signed value of the 6 bits in bits 4-9

respectively.

Here are some examples:

```
signedBits0through3: input: 0x3fa, output: 0xfffffffa 
signedBits0through3: input: 0x3f7, output: 0x07 
signedBits4through9: input: 0x38f, output: 0xfffffff8 
signedBits4through9: input: 0x18f, output: 0x18
```

```
// return the signed value in bits 0 through 4

int signedBits0through3(int v)
{
    if (((v & 15) & (1<<3))== 0) {
        return (v & 15);
    }
    else
        return ~(v & 15);
}

// return the signed value in bits 4 through 9

int signedBits4through9(int v)
{
    if (((v & 1008)&(1<<9))==(1<<9)) {
        return ~((v & 1008)>>4);
    }
    else    
        return ((v & 1008)>>4);
}
```

Any help!!

Comment: Examples aren't sufficient in general, and these ones don't seem consistent. What is the *rule?* Possibly you just have to sign-extend the 0x200 bit.

Comment: first make it into binary and capture the first 4 signed bits and return it....

Comment: Bits 4 through 9 is six bits, not 4. Please state the actual problem.

Comment: bits through 0~3 is 4 bits and yea, 4 through 9 is 6 bits. I just stated the first problem. sorry for the comfuse

Comment: So suppose you fix your question?

Comment: no... I don't understand your solution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's a lot simpler than you think. Just a mild bit of masking, sign-extending, and shifting back.

```
// return the signed value in bits 0 through 3
int signedBits0through3(int v)
{
    return ((v  & 0xf) << 28) >> 28;
}

// return the signed value in bits 4 through 9
int signedBits4through9(int v)
{
    return ((v  & 0x3f0) << 22) >> 26;
}
```

Comment: This is really awesome. But can you explain that how you determine whether the result of (v  & 0xf)is negative or positive? And whats the effect of " << 28) >> 28" you just multiply it by 28 and divide it by 28 again..... I m so curious about your answer!!!!

Comment: What about if `int` isn't 32 bit size? See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types

Comment: The left and right shifting does sign propagation. `<< 28` puts the leftmost value bit into the sign bit, then `>> 28` propagates it downwards. @Rimas You would have to adjust the shifts accordingly, of course. You can use `sizeof int * 8` and so forth. Left as an exercise for the reader ;-)